# If $x_n \to a$ and $f(x_n) \to L$ as $n \to \infty$, is it true that $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to a$?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Suppose that ${x_n}$ is a sequence converging to $a$ with $x_n \neq a$. If $f(x_n) → L$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$, then $f(x)$ approaches to $L$ as $x$ tends to $a$

by the sequential characterization of limits, this statement is correct, right?But the converse of the seqn: criteria says "for all" sequence and is it okay conclude the limit of the function using only one seqn?

Comment: Your are only assuiming something about the values of $f$ near $a$. How can that say anything about the behavior of $f(x)$ as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: Can $a=\infty$?

Comment: I'm so sorry. It should be "a" I edited the post

Comment: You need the hypothesis for all sequences converging to $a$.

Comment: What the hayellll? The question just morphed.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes. but how can I come with a counter example. Since it works for all sequences, can't we say it should work out for a specific sequence as well?

Comment: You are assuming it works for A sequence not ALL sequences.

Comment: @AlvinL So how can come up with a counterexample for this statement?

Comment: Take $f(x)=\sin (\frac 1x)$ Try to find sequences converging to $0$ which yield different limits.

Comment: @geetha290krm oh yeah. I could go for $2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ and
$2n\pi+\frac{3\pi}{2}$

Comment: Hi! Your title should reflect the core content of your question, rather than (as here) the fact that it's a true or false question. This makes it easier for other users to find relevant content. I'll edit your question to change the title, but feel free to change it to something else, as long as it's descriptive.

Comment: @BrianTung Sorry for the inconvenience I tried to add the statement to the title and the character limit was not enough. I should have put a more descriptive title. Thank you for mentioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is clearly no! Take

$f(x)=sinx$ then for $x_{n}=n\pi$ we have
$f(x_{n})=sinn\pi=0 \to 0$ but the limit

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty}sinx$ does not exists because for $x_{n}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi$ we get $f(x_{n})=1\to1$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the idea

Comment: There is no value to describing the answer as clearly something or other. If it was to the OP, they would not have asked.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$f :[0,1]\to \mathbb R,\quad x\mapsto \begin{cases} 0, &x\in [0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q \\ 1, & x\in\mathbb Q\end{cases} $$
Take any sequence $x_n$ of rationals in $[0,1]$ that converge to $1$. Then $f(x_n)\to 1$. But the limit
$ \lim _{x\to 1} f(x) $
does not exist.

Comment: Mornings. I meant the Dirichlet map.

Comment: Oh yeah I forget the Dirichlet function. Thank you so much